# Don't watch a data item in a Vue component

Tags: vue.js

What is the best practice of preventing my component from doing an update when a particular data item is updated?

I have a Vue component with the following properties:

```
data: function() {
    return {
        'orderBy': 'date_published:desc',
        'page': 1,
        'posts': []
    }
},

updated() {
    this.loadPosts();
},

methods: {
    loadPosts: function() {
        // code to AJAX in data
        this.posts = response.data;
    }
}
```

In the component, I have buttons that change the value of `orderBy` and `page`. When these values change, I want the `updated()` method to be called. However, I do not want it to be called when `posts` changes because an infinite loop will occur.

What is the best way of telling the component to stop updating when either `loadPosts()` is called, or `this.posts` changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine all the properties you want to watch into a computed property, then watch the computed property

```
data: function() {
    return {
        'orderBy': 'date_published:desc',
        'page': 1,
        'posts': []
    }
},

computed: {
    controls(){
        return {
            orderBy: this.orderBy,
            page: this.page
        }
    }
},
watch:{
    controls(){
        this.loadPosts()
    }
},
methods: {
    loadPosts: function() {
        // code to AJAX in data
        this.posts = response.data;
    }
}
```